# Check if string is all capitals using classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I need a function to check if a string is all (or mostly) capitals using classic asp. (I need to prevent users from inputting titles using all capitals.)

For example, if a string of 30 letters contains 20 or more that are capitalized, I'd need to flag it as "All capitals". So "The Count of Monte Cristo" would be fine, but "The COUNT of MONTE CRISTO" would not.

I was thinking about starting with a count of letters that match `[^A-Z]`, but how do I do that?

This needs to be in Classic ASP and not VB.

Comment: Starting with a count of letters that match [^A-Z] but how to do that?

Comment: You ask to check if all the characters are capital, but then you ask for something to check for 20 out of 30 are all capitals.   Which is it?  If it is the first my answer below will do the trick.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf It almost sounds like they are asking for the a count of all the capitalised words. To be honest the question is not clear and they haven't shown any working out for themselves, personally would just step away and flag appropriately.

Comment: Do you even know the difference between VBscript and Classic ASP? The person who provided the best answer understood the original question, so why can't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing against UCase(input) makes it an all or nothing check; I'd prefer to look at the UCase ratio:

```
Option Explicit

Function Ucasity(s)
  If Len(s) Then
     Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
     r.Global = True
     r.Pattern = "[A-Z]"
     Dim m : Set m = r.Execute(s)
     Ucasity = m.Count / Len(s)
  Else
     Ucasity = 0
  End If
End Function

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim s
For Each s In Array( _
     "UPPERCASE but not ALL OR NOTHING" _
   , "UPPERCASE" _
   , "pipapo" _
   , "UPPERCASEuppercase" _
   , "" _
)
   WScript.Echo qq(s), CStr(s = UCase(s)), UCasity(s)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 39261181.vbs
"UPPERCASE but not ALL OR NOTHING" False 0,65625
"UPPERCASE" True 1
"pipapo" False 0
"UPPERCASEuppercase" False 0,5
"" True 0
```

Comment: Always find your examples confusing at first look...where does the extra `0` come from in `0,65625`?? Then I realise it's the locale and the value is actually `0.65625`. So easy to mistake for an extra parameter.

Comment: Note that this is straight VBScript code, not ASP. In particular, you'd need to replace `WScript.Echo` with `Response.Write` to make this run in ASP.

Comment: @martha valid point. Although if people are using ASP without an understanding of the Windows Scripting Host and their differences I would be worried. They tend to go hand in hand.

Comment: @Lankymart: It is entirely possible to use ASP as it was originally intended: as a server platform. WSH has no place in that scenario. (Well, not unless your server has insanely bad security.)

Comment: @martha your missing the point. VBScript is a "hosted" language whether it's ASP, WSH or something else. The little idiosyncrasies are related to the "host". Either way the coder should know of their existence. For example `Response.Write()` is the same whether you use VBScript or JScript as are most of the ASP specific objects.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the UCase function

```
<%

dim a 
a = "This is a test 1"
dim b 
b = "THIS IS A TEST 2"

If a = ucase(a) then response.write(a & " is all upper")
If b = ucase(b) then response.write(b & " is all upper")

%>
```

Result

> THIS IS A TEST 2 is all upper